# Advantages of using centroids vs component-wise medians during clustering

Tags: clustering, mean, median

During clustering, what are the advantages of using either the component-wise median or the component-wise mean (centroid).

One of the possible advantages of the component-wise median over the mean may be the robustness to outliers, even if, with a good number of samples, outlier effects don't affect the central point of the cluster.

Are there other advantages for either one or the other alternative?

Comment: Multivariate median could be defined differently. But the greatest advantage of centroid (mean) in potentially massive tasks such clustering is sometimes is that it can be computed easily and quickly. You don't have to sort or rank data, etc.

Comment: Yes, the median requires a sort, which is much more expensive than calculating the average (centroids).

Comment: Thanks. May it be said that for good number of samples multivariate mean and median provide a similar result? And conversely, they differ more for a small number of samples?